# how to create multiple display in a line from input field using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to create a display of all my inputs in respective div ids with button onclick or any other methods to show in jquery. kindly guide me. here i am able to create onkeypress event only.

```js
function tkpreview(){
var a = document.getElementById("inp1").value;
document.getElementById("di1").innerHTML = a;

var b = document.getElementById("inp2").value;
document.getElementById("di2").innerHTML = b;

var c = document.getElementById("inp3").value;
document.getElementById("di3").innerHTML = c;

var d = document.getElementById("inp4").value;
document.getElementById("di4").innerHTML = d;

}
```

```html
<form>
<h3> display preview of my form</h3>
<div id="" class="">
    <label for="inp1">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="inp1" class="myinp" onkeypress="tkpreview()" required/>
    
    <label for="inp2">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="inp2" class="myinp" onkeypress="tkpreview()" required/>
    <br> <br>
    <label for="inp3">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="inp3" class="myinp" onkeypress="tkpreview()" required/>
    
    <label for="inp4">Contact</label>
    <input type="text" id="inp4" class="myinp" onkeypress="tkpreview()" required/>
    <br> <br>
    <button type="Submit" id="btn_1" value="" onclick="tkpreview()">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
<form>
<div id="di1" class="mydiv"></div>
<div id="di2" class="mydiv"></div>
<div id="di3" class="mydiv"></div>
<div id="di4" class="mydiv"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not change `onkeypress` to `onclick`? You don't need jQuery for that.

Comment: You could use `$('input.myinp').on('input', tkpreview);`, that way you don't have to use inline code and clutter up your HTML.

Comment: Change the button to `type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form when clicked

Comment: thanks but i want it solve through array method using jquery. kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btn_1").click(function(){
        $("#di1").text($("#inp1").val());
        $("#di2").text($("#inp2").val());
        $("#di3").text($("#inp3").val());
        $("#di4").text($("#inp4").val());
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: `val()` is only for form controls, not content elements

Comment: thanks but it is not working fine. while tested it is not showing the desired result. can you guide me how to solve it on array method in jquery.